# Partial redraw to FBO OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, framebuffer

My scene is organized into groups of elements that compose to FBOs backed by floating point textures (16 bit with alpha). These FBOs are then blended together top to bottom to produce the final scene. All FBOs are the size of the screen. When the screen size gets large (> 2048 on an Intel HD Graphics 630), the framerate plummets. This is due to fill rate issues (I have experimented with no-op leaf nodes and smaller texture formats to verify this). Is there a way to blit part of an FBO to part of another FBO? Maybe something like this before drawing a textured quad:

```
void FrameBufferManager::SetViewportFromClipBox(const Geometry::BoundingBox& clipBox)
{
    const auto& lowerLeft = clipBox.GetLowerLeft();
    const auto lx = static_cast<GLsizei>(lowerLeft.x);
    const auto ly = static_cast<GLsizei>(lowerLeft.y);
    const auto width = static_cast<GLsizei>(clipBox.GetWidth());
    const auto height = static_cast<GLsizei>(clipBox.GetHeight());
    glViewport(lx, ly, width, height);
    glScissor(lx, ly, width, height);
}
```

In the vertex shaders, the geometry is transformed such that points outside of `clipBox` will fall outside of ((-1, -1) (1, 1)). Will the above ensure that pixels outside of clipBox do not waste GPU memory bandwidth / fillrate? If not, is there any way to do this without creating a bunch of small FBOs and splitting object rendering across these based on object location?

Comment: I tested the above code and it seems to fix the perf issues on the GPU mentioned in the question if anyone requires using custom shaders for blitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to blit part of an FBO to part of another FBO?

Since OpenGL ES 3.0 you can use [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml):

> `glBlitFramebuffer` — copy a block of pixels from the read framebuffer to the draw framebuffer
>
> ```
> void glBlitFramebuffer(
>     GLint srcX0, GLint srcY0, GLint srcX1, GLint srcY1,
>     GLint dstX0, GLint dstY0, GLint dstX1, GLint dstY1,
>     GLbitfield mask, GLenum filter);
> ```

This function is also provided by the extension [**NV_framebuffer_blit**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_framebuffer_blit.txt), which is is written against OpenGL ES 2.0.